# Image height does not properly placed in div

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have div like this:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="text-center" style="background-image: url('/public/images/nano.jpg');width:100%;height:100%;height: 115px;background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <span class="styleRankingBlue px-2 text-white"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-img-overlay text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <p class="card-text mb-0 pt-1">
            <b>

            </b>
        </p>
        </p>
        <p class="card-text mb-0">
            
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I tried adding `width:100%;height:100%;` to the background image but it loads like this:

[image]

And if I say `height: 115px;` this will happen:

[image]

However I need to load it like this:

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

So how to properly do this with CSS?

Comment: Try setting your height as `100%` and width as `auto`?

Comment: @basile Still shows the top of image

Comment: why do you put height :115px when your image is much bigger ? use background-size: contain and it will show all the image. But still not as you want it

Comment: The reason it's only showing the top is because of the `height:115px`. as it is a background image it is not included as an element inside your div. that means that if you set height to 100% it sees is as 100% of an empty div. If you want that background image to be completely visible, you have to tell the div to be "this size". this should work for example: `max-width:100vw;height:619px` .. [Example code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-spence-tr9q1?file=/index.html:384-412)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play with the height and width inside your `img` tag

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdNEU.jpg" height="307px" width="309px">
```